# Attachments in SharePoint List

Tags: sharepoint-server, item-attachment

Is there anyway I can get SharePoint list attachments and save it in folder path? We have a SharePoint list with more than 1000 records. I need to download all the attachments in the list.

Regards

Comment: Explain more, i didn't understand what you mean with "save it in folder path", you mean in local ?

Comment: thats correct, save it in local server or machine.

Answer (score 1):

You can download SharePoint list Attachments using PowerShell.

Here are some articles for your reference.

Download Attachments using PowerShell – SharePoint 2010/2013:

http://www.sptechlearn.com/2016/02/download-attachments-using-powershell-sharepoint-20102013.html

http://sharepointsrikanth.blogspot.com/2014/09/powershell-script-to-download.html

SharePoint Online: Download Attachments from List using PowerShell:

https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2017/01/sharepoint-online-download-attachments-from-list-using-powershell.html